# Assign generic method to variable in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, methods, delegates, variable-assignment

How do you declare a variable that can be assigned with such method:

```
def inTransaction[A](a: =>A): A =
  if(! Session.hasCurrentSession)
    _executeTransactionWithin(SessionFactory.newSession, a _)
  else {
    a
  }
```

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 2):

As paradigmatic said, you need to assign a type. But as a workaround, you can use an object.

```
object myFunc {
  def apply[A](a: =>A): A = ???
}
```

Comment: I am using anonymous class, I was just asking if it is possible to make it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly assign a method to a variable, it must be transformed in a closure object (`Function*`). This transformation may happen implicitly or manually by adding an `_` after the function name.

Since a variable cannot be generic, you must fix the type during assignation. For instance:

```
scala> def size[A]( lst: List[A] ) = lst.size
size: [A](lst: List[A])Int

scala> var f = size[Int] _
f: List[Int] => Int = <function1>
```

Comment: I don't want to specify the Int parameter.